# object wont give attr of element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given an object which stores `li` elements, I want to find their ids:

```
$($selected).each(function(){   
    console.log($selected.attr('id'));
        $(this).fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).appendTo($list).removeClass("ui-state-highlight").fadeIn(); 
        });     
    });             
}
```

This is only giving me the first. Why?

Comment: Incidental to the question, but it looks like `$selected` is already a jQuery object, so you don't need to say `$($selected)` - `$selected.each( ... )` would work just fine.

Comment: but $selected contains values and not all of them same,so when i need to remove class i need to loop throu each of them,not so?

Comment: I think you misunderstood; yes, you need to loop through, using `.each( ... )`; that part is fine. But `$(variable)` just wraps `variable` as a jQuery object; if `variable` is already a jQuery object, it does nothing. So you could write `$($($($selected))).each( ... )` and it would still be the same as `$selected.each( ... )`

Comment: roger-got it,learned somthing..thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are calling `attr` method on the `$selected` object and `attr` only returns ID of the first selected element in jQuery collection, you should use `this.id` or `$(this).prop('id')` in the `each` callback.

```
$selected.each(function(index, element) {   
    console.log(this.id);
    // ...       
})
```

Comment: that just brouth tears to my eyes!thank you..stabbed myself for two hours around this..

Answer (score 0):

You are grabbing the `'id'` attribute of your original `$selected` object, not the individual items iterated over by `.each()`, which will be given to your callback as `this`. So you want `console.log( $(this).attr('id') )`.

There are a few other tweaks you can make, as others have pointed out, but this is your main mistake.